# `ls -l ~~` (two tilde)+ tab does not show directories starting with ~~, but users

Tags: bash, command-line, ls, autocomplete

In the `bash` shell, why does `ls -l ~~` + <kbd>Tab</kbd> not show directories starting with `~~`, but users? (all users).

The `ls -l` is just an example. If I type `~` + <kbd>Tab</kbd> in any directory, I get a list of users.

Comment: Which shell do you use? Try `ls -l ./~~` + tab

Comment: @Bodo bash, the question is not only how to autocomplete, but why is this happening?

Comment: @Jesse_b: it outputs a list with 44 users like ~~nobody, ~~news, ~~root ~~whoopsie

Comment: @Jesse_b: no space, it happens in any directory, yes.

Comment: Well, `~user` refers to the home directory of `user`, so that part is not strange (I would expect a single tilde to be complete in this way). What's slightly odd is that it completes double tilde with usernames.

Comment: That's because you're using bash programmable completion, which behaves in strange ways. I'm always disabling it on sight (`apt-get remove --purge bash-completion`), so unfortunately I cannot help you further. Hopefully some bash-completion guru pops up ;-)

Comment: Anyways, you can temporarily disable it with `shopt -u progcomp`.

Comment: @Kusalananda that's because bash's programmable is buggy. The OP would better report this as a bug, if they care about it being fixed, rather than asking for lame rationalizations. I've just tried it in a VM -- `ls ~~a<tab>` will complete to `ls ~~avahi`, but `~~avahi` will stay as is and not expand to anything.

Answer (score 1):

[`~`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html) is syntactic sugar available within Bash which is meant to expand to `$HOME`. Bash completion used to have many quirks, and is still being worked on. It used to not be able to auto-complete many filenames with special characters such as newline or asterisk, for example, and it looks like you've found another quirk.

My C-foo is not strong enough, but it looks like the answer you're looking for should be around the line

```
/* We aren't done yet.  We also support the "~user" syntax. */
```

in [lib/readline/complete.c](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/lib/readline/complete.c)

Comment: `~` expansion comes from csh and is now found in most shells. I don't know of any shell where `~` expansion is only enabled when interactive. While `~` alone expands to `$HOME`, `~user` expands to the home directory of the corresponding user. `bash` and several other shells will expand `~~` to the home directory of the user named `~` if it exists, while some other shells would consider `~` as not a valid user name in that regards. Some will have more use for tilde expansions like zsh's `~-`, `~+`, or `~<number>`  to expand to directories in the directory stack.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Bash also supports `~-`, `~+`, `~+N` and `~-N`. Clarified that I didn't mean Bash was the only shell with `~` support, but rather that it's only available within interactive mode.

Comment: tilde expansion is also available in bash when non-interactive like in all other shells. Try `bash -c 'echo ~'`

Comment: Bash also autocompletes usernames when you type a `~` and hit tab (even without the (buggy) completion scripts)

Answer (score 0):

For bash, `man readline` explains:

```
Completing
  complete (TAB)


Attempt to perform completion on the text before point.
The actual completion performed is application-specific.  

Bash, for instance, attempts completion treating the text as a 

variable (if the text begins with $), 
username (if the text begins with ~), 
hostname (if the text begins with @), or 
command (including aliases and functions) in turn.  

If none of these produces a match, filename completion is attempted.
```

The username completion can also be triggered by `M-~`.

---

...and filename completion with default `M-/` (`Esc, /` or `Alt-/`)

```
]# touch '~~ van tilde'
]# ls ~~\ van\ tilde
```

(with `ls ~~Esc/`)

---

**Completion** and **expansion** are not to be mixed up.

---

After `touch \~ftp`, and `~f+TAB` I get:

`\~ftp/` which is neither nor. The backslash shows bash recognizes a file, the slash comes from expansion as `/srv/ftp/`.

Comment: None of these explain why OP is seeing the behaviour they are seeing.

Comment: "text begins with ~"